# How do I efficiently extract all elements in a column from a dictionary whose values are 2D lists in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have a dictionary whose values are lists of lists.

```
mydict = {
"A" : [["gactacgat", "IE"],["gactacgat", "IE"]],
"G" : [["ggctacgat", "EI"],["gactacgat", "IE"]],
"C" : [["gcctacgat", "N"],["gactacgat", "IE"]],
"T" : [["gtctacgat", "IE"],["gactacgat", "IE"]]
}
```

And I am trying to create a list containing all of the elements in the second column of these 2D lists.
This is what I am doing:

```
  mylist = []
  for key in mydict.keys():
      for row in mydict[key]:
          mylist.append(row[1])
```

Is there a more efficient way of accessing a specific index from all the lists in these lists of lists than what I have done?

(I apologize if my wording was bad, and any feedback for a better title question is appreciated)

Comment: Your wording is fine, and most importantly, it matches your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions are your friend:

```
mylist = [row[1] for value in mydict.values() for row in value]
```

This uses a nested loop, but presumably a bit better optimized. Additionally, using `dict.values` saves you a key lookup at each iteration of the outer loop, and returns items in the same order as the keys would be.

Comment: If OP values are list of lists of size 2.Then indexing helps `mylist=[];for val in mydict.values():mylist.append(val[0][1]);mylist.append(val[1][1])`.

Comment: Correct, even though I don't think that's a safe assumption to make in general.

Comment: Your answer works for variable lengths. Generic solution is sometimes less efficient. If OP mentions the constraints like the list of lists is of size 2 for every key etc. Then I think we can truly suggest a efficient way I guess.

Comment: Agreed. At that point, OP should probably rethink their entire data structure, but yes, accessing a fixed number of rows directly would cut out the loop overhead.